# Why do physical quantities need to obey triangle law of vector addition to qualify as vectors?

Tags: vectors

Why do physical quantities need to obey triangle law of vector addition to qualify as vectors? Or, why do they need to satisfy mathematical operations to be called vectors?

Comment: What do you mean by "triangle law?" Do you mean tip-to-tail representation of the vectors for graphical addition? Do you mean the triangle inequality?

Answer (score 2):

It is convenient to define certain laws that a vector must follow in order to make sure that the operations we wish to perform are valid and useful. If you pick up a book on linear algebra, you will see that a vector space must satisfy certain properties such as:

1. Linearity
2. Commutativity
3. Addition of zero maintains vector.
4. Multiplication by 0 and 1 vectors gives expected result
5. Distributive law for scalar and vectors
6. Addition is defined

And some textbooks may go into more details in other properties as well. What this allows is for us to ensure that if the vectors in our chosen vector space satisfy these properties then operations like the inner and outer product are well defined, we can construct a complete basis etc.

Comment: Can u  why do they need to need to do so?

Comment: It's not so much that they physically have to follow that. I could technically define a vector however I wanted. But if my vector space does not follow the mathematical rules then I can't expect the operations between vectors to work and give the correct result.

Comment: So u mean to say that, it is experimentally verified that the quantities we know as vectors follow the different mathematical operations?

Comment: Well vectors are mathematical constructs to follow the physical rules we want. Mathematicians have designed a set of rules that ensure that the operations give sensible results in the sense of the physical interpretation.